# python Bad Interpreter error

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I am trying to install Sublime Text 2 on my linux machine and I cannot figure out how to run the python script to install it. I am fairly new to linux and never programmed in python before. I am trying to run the python script PackageSetup.py using ./PackageSetup.py but i get the error:

```
bash: ./PackageSetup.py: python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

not sure what I have to do. I have python on my machine. I can tell cause running 'python' puts me in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all I know this kind of issue can occur if you have a misspelling or mistake in the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). I see two ways to solve this issue: you can try to invoke `PackageSetup.py` via python, like `python PackageSetup.py` or you can open `PackageSetup.py` and try to find an issue in the shebang, maybe it needs to be a full path to python interpreter like `/usr/bin/python` not just `python`.

BTW, why don't you try to install it via some kind of package manager - there is a [repo](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/sublime-text-2-ubuntu-ppa.html) for debian-based distros, and I'm pretty sure that there have to be repositories for other distributives.

Comment: the shebang for their script is just #!python

Comment: i tried changing it to the full path and now it just freezes the terminal